# How do I not repeat myself in this SQL query?

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, where-clause, sql-in

I've started learning SQL and I'm trying to reduce my repetition. Can someone help with this?

```
SELECT email
FROM users 
WHERE campaign LIKE 'BBB-2'
AND test ='lions' 
OR test = 'tigers' 
OR test = 'bears';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `in`:

```
SELECT email
FROM users 
WHERE campaign = 'BBB-2' AND test IN ('lions' , 'tigers' , 'bears');
```

Notes:

- this solves a logical prescendence issue in your original query: the `OR`ed condition needed to be surrounded by parentheses
- I replaced the `LIKE` condition with an equality check; there is no point using `LIKE` when the right operand contains no wildcard

Comment: Wow thanks! Stack Overflow really does work!

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN`:

```
WHERE campaign LIKE 'BBB-2' AND
      test IN ('lions' , 'tigers' , 'bears');
```

As a bonus this will fix a logic bug in your query.  Presumably, you want the `campaign` condition to filter *all* rows, not just those with `'lions'`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below:

```
    SELECT email
    FROM users 
    WHERE campaign LIKE 'BBB-2'
    AND test IN('lions','tigers','bears')
```